# Swift: Want to use extension for existing function

Tags: swift

I definied a function:

```
func inSubfolder_(file : String, root : String) -> Bool { ... }
```

This I want also add to String as an extension:

```
extension String {
    func inSubfolder(root : String) -> Bool {
        return inSubfolder_(file : self, root : root)
    }
}
```

I like to use the same names (without "_"), but the global one need to be declared as "global", so that the extension one does not try to access itself (recursivly).
What did I miss?

Comment: These parameters must be the same

Comment: Since the parameters are different you should be able to have the same name.

Comment: That is my problem too! :-) I think it should, but it doesn't. I get an error "Extra argument 'file' in call". It tries to access itself!

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly call a function in a global scope by namespacing your call with the module name. In most cases, this will be your app's target name. If this is in the context of a playground, you'd use `Playground` instead of the module name.

```
func inSubfolder(file : String, root : String) -> Bool { ... }

extension String {
    func inSubfolder(root : String) -> Bool {
        return AppTargetName.inSubfolder(file : self, root : root)
    }
}
```